# R Plot xtick lables for each facet wraps

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am trying to show the x-labels for each facet wrap, instead of collectively it showing.
**Sample of the data, trying to plot**

```
|tenant| name    | value   |
| -----| --------|---------|
| bnl  | N > 82  |0.0551241|
| bnl  | N > 84  |0.240242 |
| bnl  | N > 88  |0.610067 |
| bnl  | N > 92  |2.40777  |
| bnl  | N > 96  |0.183061 |
| bnl  | N < 76  |0.540545 |
| bnl  | N < 82  |0.748700 |
| bnl  | N = 96  |95.7550  |
| gnl  | N > 82  |0.0209527|
| gnl  | N > 84  |0.112621 |
| gnl  | N > 88  |0.216729 |
| gnl  | N > 92  |1.38681  |
| gnl  | N > 96  |0.217384 |
| gnl  | N < 76  |0.157800 |
| gnl  | N < 82  |0.202979 |
| gnl  | N = 96  |97.8425  |
| knl  | N > 82  |0.0506792|
| knl  | N > 84  |0.175074 |
| knl  | N > 88  |0.458416 |
| knl  | N > 92  |2.13620  |
| knl  | N > 96  |2.51016  |
| knl  | N < 76  |1.13414  |
| knl  | N < 82  |1.21016  |
| knl  | N = 96  |93.4593  |
| mnl  | N > 82  |0.126081 |
| mnl  | N > 84  |0.460583 |
| mnl  | N > 88  |0.680839 |
| mnl  | N > 92  |3.72686  |
| mnl  | N > 96  |0.0648418|
| mnl  | N < 76  |0.651506 |
| mnl  | N < 82  |0.997329 |
| mnl  | N = 96  |93.9435  |
| mpnl | N > 82  |0.117108 |
| mpnl | N > 84  |0.303749 |
| mpnl | N > 88  |0.639825 |
```

Plotted data -
[image: plotted_data]

Desired to have the X-axis label plot for each wrap instead of down as collective.
here what i am trying -

```
data %>%
filter(name != "N < 82" & name != "N < 84" & name != "N > 84") %>%
ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = tenant)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
scale_y_continuous(name = "Percentage of cells",
                 labels = function(x) paste0(x, '%')) +
facet_wrap(~tenant) +
theme(text = element_text(size = 12), legend.position = "none", legend.title = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

Comment: You have left a number of questions on stack overflow where folks have pointed out that a minimal reproducible example with data is helpful. Please make an effort to post such an example. A large string of unformatted data is not a minimal example. Also, when someone solves your problem, upvote the question and "accept" it by clicking the check mark

Comment: @colebrookson - dude, i am new here, wait for it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `scales="free_x"` to your facet.

```r
data %>%
  filter(name != "N < 82" & name != "N < 84" & name != "N > 84") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = tenant)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Percentage of cells",
                     labels = function(x) paste0(x, '%')) +
  facet_wrap(~tenant, scales="free_x") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 12), legend.position = "none",
        legend.title = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: u mean clicking and posting answer your question.

Comment: No. If you click on the link I gave, it lists two things to consider doing when an answer is donated to you: upvote it (not what I said) and accept it. It then provides another link to explain why accepting is s good thing, that may be another good read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: my sincere apologies, i missed the green yes tick ...  i was thinking about the auto correcting the question posted, something about it, i did marked yes for all other ones too.. thanks again.